# Uniqueness of the complex extension of a real linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $V$ be a complex vector space and $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-linear functional. Furthermore, define $\tilde{f}: V \to \mathbb{C}$ with $\tilde{f}(x) := f(x) - i f(ix)$.

**I was already able to show** that $\tilde{f}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear functional and it holds $\operatorname{Re}\tilde{f} = f$.

**What I need to show** now is that if we would have another $\mathbb{C}$-linear functional $g : V \to \mathbb{C}$ with $\operatorname{Re}g = f$ then it must be $\tilde{f} = g$.

**My thoughts so far**:
If the statement would be true we would get $\operatorname{Im}(g)(x) = - f(ix)$ for every $x \in V$. I tried to assume the existence of an $x$ such that we have an inequality and searched for a contradiction but it did not work out.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tilde{f} - g = h$ is a linear functional with real part zero, i.e. $h(v) \in i \mathbb{R}$ for all $v \in V$. But linear functionals are either surjective or zero; we've ruled out the former, so $h = 0$ as desired.